# In latest 2020 version of Android Studio there is no more Android Device Monitor, what replaces it and how can I search logs?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-device-monitor

In Android Studio until it was deprecated and then removed there was a tool window in the then eclipse based IDE called Android Device Monitor.  That appears to be removed and not replaced.

[image: app screen]

The only thing you can do now, that I know of, is open a text console and type adb logcat, which is a major loss of functionality over what I could do in Android Device Monitor, where for example, I can filter and see only output from certain app bundle ids (com.yourcompany.yourapp) or containing certain keywords (WiFi, Camera, whatever you wanted).

How can I:

1. View in realtime, and have relevant filtered ADB LOG results similar to Android Device Monitor in a modern Android Studio?
2. If NOT possible to do this inside there, do I need to just run the old tool externally or is there a modern replacement way?

You would think that when one thing is deprecated, a replacement would be made?

Comment: See: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat#filtering The LogCat panel tab is at the bottom of Android Studio assuming you've 'Window'->'Reset Default Layout'. Unless some other feature of Android Device Monitor is missing?

Comment: I think that's the answer.